# Watching moments in a cat's life: friction

Tags: riddle, mystery

It's in the little moments
It's in the grand schemes
In galaxies, as well as the life story of each sand grain,
It drives some insane, it keeps some in their lane, it leads some to abstain
Me? I'm learning to let it be

It's in the finest times of my life
It's in my biggest picture, and in every plot in between
I garden with it, I eat with it
I love the space it makes, I hate the spaces it makes
I am of the spaces it makes, and I'll make a space too

---

> *"LIVE"* it says, "*I am on my way...*"

---

*WHAT* **IS** ***IT***?

---

*Clues...*

> It is tangible, yet not itself material.
>
>  It carries mystery, yet is itself strikingly empirical.
>
>  ~~~
>
>  It is truly an in between, making it hard to guess.
>
>  It is an inherent part of life, and puts every one to rest.

The title is a stretch in terms of a clue, and came as mere muse to me in a mystical mindset. You needn't explain it to identify ***it***. All other parts of a poem fit ***it*** fairly well I think. In due time, I'll add another two lines *(clues)* to the poem, which hint much more clearly at the solution.

Comment: ... Destiny!  :)

Comment: Slightly less ambiguous than that, @KeyboardWielder. Nice try. Sounds like an answer by the way, maybe make it >! one

Comment: Sorry I may not have been clear enough about the raw tangibility of this immaterial thing - important clues, which I have now added.

Comment: Added two more lines to the poem which should help immensely, with the last word redacted as it would practically give the answer away. Also noted the title was merely muse, and particularly muse to a mystical mindset, which may be required to see the answer as well fit to this poem as I.

Comment: filled in the blank for the poetic clues, that should help

Comment: Oh good, I was thinking that the redacted word was _work_, and perhaps the answer either _energy_ or _change_.  This certainly changes things, except that we are still stumped!  :)

Comment: @KeyboardWielder *change* is close, but the solution is a grim presentation of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally go with :

> Death

mostly thanks to your latest hints.

> The one clue that put me on this track is :
>
>  "LIVE" it says, "I am on my way...".
>
>  
>  For me this doesn't fit the concept of a process like aging or growing, but rather an inevitability. Something that is part of everyone's life (this excludes illnesses like cancer). Death is a universal constant, is empirically evident and everyone will experience it. It is shrouded in the mystery of the beyond and creates empty spaces in people's lives.

Although I'm having a hard time interpreting this clue:

> I garden with it, I eat with it

Comment: Very good! This is the correct answer I had intended and written the poems about. I admired a cat's behavior and recognized that the fine moment in its life would inevitably end, as would my own.

Comment: What do you eat that does not come with the death of something? How have you ever gardened without death; the ending of rocks to become soils, the ending of living creatures to contribute to organic matter/compost/fertilizer... Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you. I haven't thought about it that way. It definitely makes sense. Some life has to end in order for the next one to take place.

Comment: @cr0: This is the word that naturally came to mind after your last hint.  But I could not (and still cannot) see how it fits these parts:  leads some to abstain, learning to let it be, in the finest times of my life, ... and the last 2 lines.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I will explain those lines here:

Comment: I'm learning to let it be, as in, to not worry about the unavoidable ending of a moment or of a life, but to simply let it come as it will and to make the most of the moments of life.

Comment: In the finest times in my life, as in, it is in the finest resolution of time - every moment comes to an end. This is also especially true for those most enjoyable moments, the finest of them, which can seem to meet their death too soon.

Comment: Last 2 lines: *I love the space it makes, I hate the spaces it makes-I am of the spaces it makes, and I'll make a space too* refer to empty places in life left by death. E.g. the cat I was inspired by was with me because of a space left for it since a past pet faced its death some time ago. In that light, I love the spaces it makes. On the other hand, one can be pained by the death of a loved one and the emptiness it creates, thereby hating the spaces it makes. I am of its spaces: without death overpopulation would've limited the potential for my birth. I too will die, making space for others.

Comment: Do those make sense, or was I stretching it/expecting some mind reading for this riddle?

Comment: There's also a parallel that may be found if not intended: plots as in cemetery plots. Additionally, cats mythically have nine lives, so they would experience this multiple times. Re: moment**s**.

Comment: @cr0: As a poem in a mystic mindset, I appreciate your ideas.  But as a puzzle, it was perhaps difficult to arrive at that as a conclusive answer, while ruling out other answers.

Comment: Oh, thought it might have been "patience"

Comment: @nine9 patience is a good answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @KeyboardWielder. I see now I need to be more careful about narrowing down possible riddle answers to just one.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really an answer, more an observation that I'm putting here rather than in a comment because I can use spoiler blocks here:

> It seems like a pun on "mew"/"mu" is involved. $\mu$ is traditionally used to denote a coefficient of friction (hence the old not very funny physicists' joke: Two cats are sliding down a roof; which will last longest before it falls off? The one with the higher $\mu$) as well as various other things in physics; and it would explain the friction in the title as well as "it came as mere muse to me".

I'm not sure this has anything much to do with the actual answer, though; *cr0* seems to be indicating that it's not highly relevant.

Comment: Your observations are correct. Most importantly, that the title is not highly relevant. I think the title could only make sense after the riddle has been solved, and even then it may only hold meaning to me who experienced the musing moment with a mystical mindset.

Comment: Might be of interest:  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18518/do-i-hear-a-cat

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer :

> I think it's related to atoms or ions : "cat" in the title actually refers to "cation", and atomic friction does exist ; atoms / ions are in everything, so it explains the 1st paragraph, with the 2 last lines concerning their movement ? Then for the 2nd paragraph, all the things with "space" could refer to the space between atoms, etc.

Comment: Great interpretation, though not my intended answer. I'd almost have to give it to you, but it still falls short of at least one clue - the quote with regards to it: *"LIVE" it says, "I am on my way..."* Though, with a mystical mind (which may be needed for this riddle anyway), one could make this fit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably wrong but, here's my attempt are you:

> Faith

It's in the little moments

> All the same things that happen in life form 1 big thing.

It's in the grand schemes

> The grand plot of your life.

In galaxies, as well as the life story of each sand grain,

> Faith is everywhere, each sand grain has to be in the right place to make the right thing happen. In space and far far away in the galaxy something might happen also because of faith!

It drives some insane, it keeps some in their lane, it leads some to abstain

> Some people go nuts over faith and some ignore it/ don't believe in it.

Me? I'm learning to let it be

> I'm just letting thing happen the way they are.

It's in the finest times of my life

> George Mueller – “I have joyfully dedicated my whole life to the object of exemplifying how much may be accomplished by prayer and faith.”

It's in my biggest picture, and in every plot in between

> Faith is the big picture to us all. What happens to everyone else and the world itself. But also in every small issue and thing for our own.

I garden with it, I eat with it

> Faith is in everything, you eat because it's chosen you ate, garden, driver a car, walk in a pile of poo, everything you do is called upon by faith.

I love the space it makes, I hate the spaces it makes
I am of the spaces it makes, and I'll make a space too

> This answer could be improved feel free: According to faith, faith creates everything and makes everything happen, the good and the bad things in life.
>  You make space and I make space too. I'm in the space that is made by faith.

Hint 1:

> "LIVE" it says, "I am on my way..."
>  ==> HERE
>  I'm on my way here - Ryan Tedder? Which sings about faith.

Clues:

1)

> It is tangible, yet not itself material.
>  ==> Faith isn't material.

2)

> It carries mystery, yet is itself strikingly empirical.
>  ==> Faith is mysterious since none knows what will happen.

Comment: Nice interpretation, but incorrect answer. Faith is not material, but is it tangible or less ambiguous than the answer of *Desinty*? Faith is certainly mysterious, but is it strikingly empirical? Faith is forever a mystery, to be doubted by some and believed in by others by their own faith itself.

Comment: @cr0 I'll keep searching :) I must find it!

Answer (score 0):

> Balance!
>
>  Balance is one of the things that holds every living thing including galaxies and sand grain!
>
>  It does make people insane when they come in touch with a balanced soul and it puts one in envy immediately, for some it serves as an inspiration and hence motivate them to gain it! Since it's another energy really, I would let it be and let it do its job!
>
>  With balance within situations turn out to be ideal and favourable as it gives a unique strength to manipulate if necessary and let it be given one the wisdom to choose former or the latter depending on the situation!
>
>  It surely helps the person tapping into it and it helps keep a space with other people who sometimes are too smart for Google to handle!
>
>  Within it lives and outside its shown, what it does inside materialises outside helping one be a creator of his/her own space!

Comment: What causes the spoiler to barf like this?  I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: I too have no clue, it happening only on this page!! Any suggestions on your end!!??

Comment: It's happened to me before as well.  No idea.

Comment: The answer which the poem is based on, and which is far more fitting I think, is far more grim than this.

Comment: @cr0  if I have to add few perceptives, I would go with death and birth cycle to restore balance!! An old moment should die for the new experience to be born, old plant must die for a new seed to reap, so I thought balance is the cause for death and birth effect!! Will wait to see the right answer surely a deep riddle, just wondering away to find the right word u r looking for :)